# screen recorder app: good quality videos with less size

Tags: screen-recording, video-recording

So I am looking for a screenrecorder to install on my laptop. My aim is to have a good quality for videos with a small size (expect 1MB/min).

Answer (score 2):

### OBS-Studio / Open Broadcaster Software

You didn't mention a platform but I assume Windows or Linux or MacOS

If That is the case I reccomend [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).
It is open-source, free of cost and comes with many features.
I have just tried reccording my own screen and at the default settings (high quality) with `1920x1080 at 60fps` I got `~5Mib` with a one minute video. You could of course lower the bitrate, fps and resolution to achieve less. Default format is `.mkv`. But you can choose from:

1. `.flv`
2. `.mp4`
3. `.mov`
4. `.mkv`
5. `.ts`
6. `.m3u8`

You can also directly stream to a service like Twitch or YouTube of Facebook.

As Input you can choose pretty much anything. Full Screen, single Window, area, webcam, Audio only...And of couse you can add them to get what you need.
And you can add overlays as you might have seen on YouTube and Twitch.

Answer (score 0):

Minitool Video Converter is a great software for screen recording on windows. It has Video Converter in its name. But it also has a function to record the screen.

Link to download it -
https://cdn2.minitool.com/?p=vc&e=vc-free

Some screenshots -

[image: Minitool Video Converter Screenshot]

[image: Minitool Screen Recorder Screenshot]

You can find the full tutorial for Minitool Video Converter on this site -
https://videoconvert.minitool.com/video-converter/minitool-video-converter-manual.html

It also has many other features like the youtube video download and video converter. It can convert 1080p to 4k, mp4 to mp3, 4k to 780p and much more. It supports a wide range of video and audio formats.

Comment: Welcome Ninad.  Within a period of 15 hours, you posted 6 answers recommending 2 products.  As such, your posts have been flagged by our community.  Do you have any affiliation with either product?  If so, please disclose your affiliation, in full, within each answer.  Please also add more details to each answer explaining how it fulfills the question's requirements.  Thanks, and welcome!